# Error in defining validation string

Tags: ios, iphone, validation

I have written code to validate US zip code...but it is giving me error that unknown escape sequence \d which is in validation string.
Code:

```
- (BOOL)zipcodevalidation:(NSString *)zipstring {

    NSString *emailRegex = @"(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:zipstring];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslashes so that the string does not interpreted them as escape sequences that are used in strings like `\t`, `\n` etc

```
@"(^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$)";
```

Comment: when I enter 00000 .Is this valid according to this validation code?

Answer (score 0):

try this for US Zip code valiadtion

```
- (BOOL)zipcodevalidation:(NSString *)zipstring {

    NSString *emailRegex = @"(^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$)";


    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:zipstring];
}
```

Comment: when I enter 00000 .Is this valid according to this validation code?